# Combined group by using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Imagine a `pandas`data frame given by

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': range(1, 10),
    'mfr': ('a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'd', 'd', 'f'),
    'vmn': ('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'D')
})
```

which gives the following table

```
   id mfr vmn
0   1   a   A
1   2   b   A
2   3   a   B
3   4   c   C
4   5   d   D
5   6   e   E
6   7   d   F
7   8   d   F
8   9   f   D
```

I wish to determine which `id`'s belong to eachother by grouping either by `mfr`and/or `vmn`. I can easily assign a group id by using one of the other by

```
df['groupby_mfr'] = df.groupby('mfr').grouper.group_info[0]
df['groupby_vmn'] = df.groupby('vmn').grouper.group_info[0]
```

which gives the following

```
   id mfr vmn  groupby_mfr  groupby_vmn
0   1   a   A            0            0
1   2   b   A            1            0
2   3   a   B            0            1
3   4   c   C            2            2
4   5   d   D            3            3
5   6   e   E            4            4
6   7   d   F            3            5
7   8   d   F            3            5
8   9   f   D            5            3
```

Now I want to combine this to a new group id so the resulting data frame becomes like this

```
   id mfr vmn  groupby_mfr  groupby_vmn  combined_group
0   1   a   A            0            0               0
1   2   b   A            1            0               0
2   3   a   B            0            1               0
3   4   c   C            2            2               1
4   5   d   D            3            3               2
5   6   e   E            4            4               3
6   7   d   F            3            5               2
7   8   d   F            3            5               2
8   9   f   D            5            3               2
```

The first two rows are the same since `vmn` are equal. The third are also the same group since row 3 and 1 are the same for `vmn`. And so on...

Note also that this will be run on multiple columns with many rows so performance is much appreciated as well.

Comment: It's not clear how `combined_group` is calculated, could you elaborate?

Comment: It seems need graph. I think `networkx` is necessary here.

Comment: Groupby can take multiple labels, I believe that’s the best approach (groupby on both labels then use grouper to create a new column.

Comment: @RoyShahaf that wouldn't work. That would make more distinct group than I ask for here.

Comment: For two columns you can use `networkx` and its `connected_components`. However, I'm not sure how to extend that to multiple columns.

Comment: @Shaido is it possible to provide a minimal example?

Comment: @mr.bjerre You can see here how to find the groups: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086731/how-to-group-a-pandas-dataframe-which-has-a-list-of-combinations Afterwards you can create a dictionary and transform one of the old columns to the group column. However, as far as I can see it will only work for two columns :/

Comment: @Shaido very nice thank you. I can use multiple by simply using the newly added group for each time. I think that would work!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments in the original post it can be solved by using [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/).

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': range(1, 10),
    'mfr': ('a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'd', 'd', 'f'),
    'vmn': ('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'D')
})

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'mfr', 'vmn')
Gcc = nx.connected_components(G)

connected_map = dict()
for g, ids in enumerate(Gcc):
    for id in ids:
        connected_map[id] = g

df['combined_group'] = df['mfr'].map(connected_map)
```

which yields

```
   id mfr vmn  combined_group
0   1   a   A               0
1   2   b   A               0
2   3   a   B               0
3   4   c   C               1
4   5   d   D               2
5   6   e   E               3
6   7   d   F               2
7   8   d   F               2
8   9   f   D               2
```